# After compositing , the 3d model gets faint and translucent in the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, compositing-nodes

i was following the CGGeeks VFX trick shots , i had downloaded the assets and was making the trick shot , but the problem appeared in the last step , COMPOSITING , after compositing , the fake ball get faint and translucent (is this property called alpha?) , how to fix this

[image]

as you can see the ball is very faint in the sky

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of the compositing nodes. Don't make us guess.

Comment: okay posting in a min

Comment: never mind solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like i was not key-framing the factor node in the compositing properly , the factor was increasing from 0 to 1 in 70 frames but it was supposed to remain 1 during those frames